# Sending e-mail based on status of previous sub-step

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I want to send an email based on status the of a sub-task executed 2 steps before.

In the current action `Send an email`, I'm using the `runAfter` event to state the name of the action that failed:

```
"runAfter": {"HTTP_2": ["Failed"]}
```

However system does not allow this and I get the following error message.

```
The action HTTP_2 must belong to the same level as action as Send-an-email.
```

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot or the code of your workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which was simple in the end, I just had to switch to 'advanced mode' when entering the condition and enter

```
 @not(equals(outputs('HTTP_2')['statusCode'], 200))
```

You can thus refer to any step in the workflow.

See attached what the full solution looked like to get a better idea:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxJRk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error occurs when you are trying to runAfter a step in a different scope.  Is the "send_email" step within a condition, scope, or loop?  If so the entire condition/scope/loop would need the runAfter (or you would need to have send_email outside of the scope).  Other than that it should work.  Let me know.